# Can't understand the images generated by applying Torch functions "overlay" in combination with "to_pil_image"

Tags: python, pytorch, overlay

I'm trying to visualize the results from GradCAM analysis.
But I can't understand the images generated using "overlay" and "to_pil_image".

My questions are:

1. why test_img_1 is not the same as test_img_2?
   [test_img_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpKlO.png)
   [test_img_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o41Jt.png)
2. why test_img_2 is like a mess
3. looking at the tensor of test_img_1, why there were upper and lower limits imposed to the channels (40 to 190)?
4. how can I remove the limits and obtain the "natural" values?
   [tensor_1_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov4X8.png)
   [tensor_2_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blyGR.png)

Here is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as T
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from torchcam.utils import overlay_mask
from torchvision.transforms.functional import to_pil_image

from PIL import Image
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance


# Functions for PIL/tensor convertion

transform_PIL_Tensor = T.Compose([T.PILToTensor()])
transform_Tensor_PIL = T.ToPILImage()

# background image
img_bg = torch.FloatTensor(3, 224, 224) 
img_bg[0][:,:]=0.4
img_bg[1][:,:]=0.4
img_bg[2][:,:]=0.4

# result from GradCAM
activation_map = torch.FloatTensor(1,7,7)
activation_map[0] = torch.Tensor([[0.0741, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0177, 0.0373, 0.0608, 0.0483],
        [0.0493, 0.0132, 0.3685, 0.5149, 0.2178, 0.0942, 0.0719],
        [0.1146, 0.2910, 0.8207, 1.0000, 0.7374, 0.3378, 0.1407],
        [0.1796, 0.3862, 0.6545, 0.7378, 0.9528, 0.5379, 0.0992],
        [0.1412, 0.2769, 0.6266, 0.7642, 0.9349, 0.4842, 0.0013],
        [0.0414, 0.0000, 0.2215, 0.2465, 0.0810, 0.0000, 0.0234],
        [0.1908, 0.0792, 0.0582, 0.1163, 0.0664, 0.1111, 0.1783]])

# merge the 2 background image with the CAM mask
test_img_1 = overlay_mask(to_pil_image(img_bg), to_pil_image(activation_map[0], mode="F"), alpha=0.4)
test_img_1.show()

test_img_2 = overlay_mask(to_pil_image(img_bg), transform_Tensor_PIL(activation_map[0]), alpha=0.4)
test_img_2.show()

test_img_3 = overlay_mask(transform_Tensor_PIL(img_bg), transform_Tensor_PIL(activation_map[0]), alpha=0.4)
test_img_3.show()

# Double check the tensor values
tensor_1 = transform_PIL_Tensor(test_img_1)
tensor_2 = transform_PIL_Tensor(test_img_2)

x = range(0, 224)

# plotting the rows of the lower half of the tensors
# test_img_1
channel = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
for row in range(110, 220, 5):
    y = [value for value in tensor_1[channel][row, 0:224].cpu()]
    ax.plot(x, y);

# test_img_2
channel = 0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
for row in range(110, 220, 5):
    y = [value for value in tensor_2[channel][row, 0:224].cpu()]
    ax.plot(x, y);
```

Comment: Your post seems not focused. I suggest you to read [ask] to see that you should focus on one question. For the 1. they are similar, but as one have transformed data it's not the same. 2. Maybe because data isn't transformed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.